# Using Abp framework - Why does my endpoint naming gets distorted?

Tags: c#, .net, abp

Hello i got a very simple service that looks like this:

```
 public class LessonAppService :ApplicationService,
    ILessonService //implement the IBookAppService
    {
        private readonly IRepository<Lesson, Guid> _lessonRepository;

        public LessonAppService(IRepository<Lesson, Guid> lessonRepository)
        {
            _lessonRepository = lessonRepository;
        }

        public async Task CreateLessonAsync(CreateLessonDTO input)
        {
            try
            {
                var lesson = ObjectMapper.Map<CreateLessonDTO, Lesson>(input);
                await _lessonRepository.InsertAsync(lesson);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }
```

The api route thats created from this is :
/api/app/lesson/lesson

While all the other endpoints look like this:
/api/account/login

Any idea on why? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ABP Framework sets *route path* as **app** to distinguish the module endpoints with your own endpoints. You can remove the route path or change whenever you want by configuring the `AbpAspNetCoreMvcOptions`.

Open your web/host module class and configure the `AbpAspNetCoreMvcOptions` options as below to set a new *route path*:

```cs
Configure<AbpAspNetCoreMvcOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ConventionalControllers
        .Create(typeof(MyProjectApplicationModule).Assembly, opts =>
            {
                opts.RootPath = ""; //by default it's 'app'
            });
});
```

Then your route convention will be changed. For more info see this documentation: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/API/Auto-API-Controllers#route